# Using Intersect to combine multiple layers: correct and zero results

Tags: arcgis-desktop, intersect

I have four rasters with cells of 5x5 arc minutes. I transformed the rasters to vectors/ shapefiles. The cells overlap, so I used intersect to combine the layers. It dawns on me that this was not very efficient, and clip might have done a better/ faster job. Nonetheless, it should have yielded the correct results.

However, for some reason I receive most awkward results: For three of the four layers, seemingly every FID is double. When looking at each of these pairs, one sees that the fourth layer displays a zero one row and the correct value for the other row. I know that the value > zero is correct, because this is the value I get when I check the original shapefile.

What has gone wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: The question isn't very clear, what are you expecting to see in the results (a diagram may help to clarify). A Union may be a better option for combining the four shapefiles.

Comment: I tried Union and the results are the same, but probably Union is more efficient. However, I found out what apparently caused the issue; I explain with an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Apparenetly an error occurred when converting the raster to a polygon. I polygonised the raster again and re-did the operation and no problems ocurred.

FYI: The problem I had looked as follows:

FID_layer1 value_layer1 FID_layer2 value layer2

.........1................5...................1...............10

.........20..............0...................1...............10

.........2................8...................1...............13

.........21..............0...................1...............13

ArcGIS basically treated layer 1 like two layers. One with the correct values, and one consisting solely of zeros.